# Show dialog from onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: java, android

I am trying to show my AlertDialog from menu Toolbar and have this exception with this code:

```
case R.id.about: {
    final AlertDialog.Builder aboutDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this);
    aboutDialog.setTitle(mCtx.getResources()
        .getString(R.string.about_tests))
        .setCancelable(true)                           
        .setMessage(mCtx.getResources().getString(R.string.description_tests))                        
        .setPositiveButton(mCtx.getResources().getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                googleRateClick();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(mCtx.getResources().getString(R.string.not_now), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    aboutDialog.show();
}
```

```
1433-1433/MYPACKAGE E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity MYPACKAGE.activity.SplashActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{d3dca6c V.E..... R......D 0,0-729,665} that was originally added here
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
                at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
                at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
                at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
                at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:987)
                at MYPACKAGE.SplashActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(SplashActivity.java:90)
```

Comment: Have you checked other android.view.WindowLeaked questions (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android.view.WindowLeaked)

Comment: Yes, the context was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is don't pass getApplicationContext() into Dialog Builder

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `break;` instruction in the case statement.
I think that's your issue. You might as well check if  you call `finish();` method , because this error usually tells you that your dialog is showing from a closed activity

Comment: Yeah, my bad with break but it doesn't help. Maybe it is due to emulator.